# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-permissions

The app is working perfectly fine on several of my devices but when i checked the app on "Test Lab" of firebase, the app crashes as soon as it is built. The logcat that i achieved from firebase is as follows. Please let me know if you need anything else.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1212, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.rafay.nupointtracker/com.example.rafay.nupointtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rafay.nupointtracker, PID: 16273
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1212, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.rafay.nupointtracker/com.example.rafay.nupointtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4920)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4963)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1848)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission: com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(IPackageManager.java:3542)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ApplicationPackageManager.java:602)
        at android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity.java:4214)
        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityCompat.java:554)
        at com.karan.churi.PermissionManager.PermissionManager.checkResult(PermissionManager.java:97)
        at com.example.rafay.nupointtracker.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7263)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4916)
        ... 9 more
```

TIA!

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?